# Unreal Engine - ERROR: Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, multiplayer, oculusquest

I'm trying to build my project to launch it into my Oculus (Meta) Quest 2, the exact build that I'm choosing is Android (ASTC). But when I try to build, I get the following error

> UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)):   ERROR: Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set 'PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;' in SteamShared.build.cs to override.
> PackagingResults: Error: Missing precompiled manifest for 'SteamShared'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set 'PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;' in SteamShared.build.cs to override.

I added that line `PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;` to the **SteamShared.build.cs** file but it didn't change anything, the error persists.

Here's my Project.Build.cs

```
PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;

PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "HeadMountedDisplay", "UMG", "LibOVRPlatform"}); //, "OnlineSubsystem"

PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "FirebaseFeatures", "OnlineSubsystem", "OnlineSubsystemOculus", "OnlineSubsystemSteam" });
```

So I'm also using the plugin AdvancedSessions & AdvancedSteamSessions. These plugins are in the Engine's plugins but also in the Project's plugins.

But the SteamSharedModule Plugin that's giving me the error is only in the engine (at C:\Epic\UE_4.27\Engine\Plugins\Runtime\Steam), and the OnlineSubsystemSteam Plugin is also only in the engine (at C:\Epic\UE_4.27\Engine\Plugins\Online).

When I try to disable the SteamSharedModule Plugin, it says "This plugin is required by OnlineSubsystemSteam", and when I try to disable the plugin OnlineSubsystemSteam, it says "This plugin is required by AdvancedSteamSessions".

**NOTE**: The multiplayer functionality I have made it in blueprints, but the project isn't completely in Blueprints, I do have some C++ classes.